# Displaying 2 results when only one should display. Java intro

Tags: java, if-statement

```
if(first == second || first == third || second == third)
{
    System.out.println("Isosceles Triangle");
}
if(first == second && first == third && second == third)
{
    System.out.println("Equilateral Triangle");
}
if(first != second && first != third && second != third)
    System.out.println("Scalene Triangle");
```

I want it to where if only 2 sides are equal then Isosceles will be displayed but as of right now it displays both Isosceles and Equilateral when all sides are equal.

Comment: Research `if/else if/else` statements

Comment: Why downvoted? This is a perfectly valid question for a new contributor...

Comment: If all three are equal then two will be equal. Both triangles will match. You could check the most limiting conditions first (Equilateral) then add an else so the isosceles check only runs if the Equilateral fails.

Comment: @Nikolas I agree. We need to think a little before downvoting.

Comment: @GBlodgett Looks like I taught you to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This Link shows how to use else if

https://www.javatpoint.com/java-if-else

I also shortened up some of you conditions:

IF first = second AND first = third THEN second = third

Scalene will be printed if the triangle is not Isosceles or Equilateral(no checks)

```
if(first == second || first == third || second == third)
{
    System.out.println("Isosceles Triangle");
}
else if(first == second && first == third)
{
    System.out.println("Equilateral Triangle");
}
else{
    System.out.println("Scalene Triangle");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if all sides are equal, it's equilateral.
Otherwise, if any two sides are equal, it's isosceles.
Otherwise, it's scalene.

"Otherwise" is expressed using the keyword `else`.

```
if (first==second && second==third) {
    System.out.println("Equilateral.");
} else if (first==second || second==third || first==third) {
    System.out.println("Isosceles.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Scalene.");
}
```

We check the conditions in this order, because the condition we are checking for isosceles triangles also applies to equilateral triangles.